# Invalid argument for cdesc-c.ri

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why am I getting this error?

```
c:\Ruby192>gem install rails
Successfully installed activesupport-3.0.9
Successfully installed builder-2.1.2
Successfully installed i18n-0.5.0
Successfully installed activemodel-3.0.9
Successfully installed rack-1.2.3
Successfully installed rack-test-0.5.7
Successfully installed rack-mount-0.6.14
Successfully installed tzinfo-0.3.28
Successfully installed abstract-1.0.0
Successfully installed erubis-2.6.6
Successfully installed actionpack-3.0.9
Successfully installed arel-2.0.10
Successfully installed activerecord-3.0.9
Successfully installed activeresource-3.0.9
Successfully installed mime-types-1.16
Successfully installed polyglot-0.3.1
Successfully installed treetop-1.4.9
Successfully installed mail-2.2.19
Successfully installed actionmailer-3.0.9
Successfully installed thor-0.14.6
Successfully installed rdoc-3.6.1
Successfully installed railties-3.0.9
Successfully installed rails-3.0.9
23 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for activesupport-3.0.9...
Installing ri documentation for builder-2.1.2...
Installing ri documentation for i18n-0.5.0...
Installing ri documentation for activemodel-3.0.9...
Installing ri documentation for rack-1.2.3...
Installing ri documentation for rack-test-0.5.7...
Installing ri documentation for rack-mount-0.6.14...
Installing ri documentation for tzinfo-0.3.28...
Installing ri documentation for abstract-1.0.0...
Installing ri documentation for erubis-2.6.6...
Installing ri documentation for actionpack-3.0.9...
Installing ri documentation for arel-2.0.10...
Installing ri documentation for activerecord-3.0.9...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EINVAL)
    Invalid argument - ./</cdesc-<.ri
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an error when generating the ri documentation. I run into them from time to time and its nothing to worry about unless you want to use the built in documentation.

Usually I don't install the documentation because its available online and there are better resources.
Try running:

```
gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

That skips the document generation and makes gem installation much faster, it also saves space if you don't ever use the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Updating rdoc fixed it for me:

```
gem install rdoc
gem install rails
```

The bad news, though: Once that was solved, I ran straight into the next bug. "Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.10... file 'lib' not found". Unfortunately there isn't any [fix for this yet](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1646).